# how to change images to buttons in textview to call another activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

Using textview with background image,and with two more images, now i want to make these two images to work as buttons for me (Back & Order Button) like - iPHONE, because by use of these buttons i want to call another activities, i am placing my xml textview

```
    <TextView
   android:id="@+id/actionbar"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="40dip"
   android:background="@drawable/header"
   android:drawableLeft="@drawable/back"
   android:drawableRight="@drawable/final_order"
   android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
   android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
   android:shadowDx="1"
   android:shadowDy="1"
   android:shadowRadius="1"
   android:text="Pizza"
   android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
   android:textSize="25dp"
   android:textStyle="bold" />
```

please write some brief code to achieve this target

Answer (score 1):

you can use ImageButton instead of textview

OR

textview itself has a onclickevent

e.g

```
textview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                               // call your activities using intent from here

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but brother i am using two images, one on left and other on right side,if it's possible so please write few lines of code

Comment: How can i make header with text and buttons like in iOS

Comment: can you post IOS link which implement this ?? so i may get your question clearly Bcoz when i paste this in my xml file it looks fine

Comment: nd also i can click on this textview  BTW nice  PIZZA :):)

Answer (score 0):

its very easy, this is my header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/button_up" 
    android:layout_width="48dp" 
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/undo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/path"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" 
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_up"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_play"
    android:text="@string/path" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_play"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_settings"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/play" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_settings"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/settings" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

i include it in front in activity_main.xml which is the default xml for my app. After include there is separator line and next is my listview whit items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="4dp"
android:background="@color/gray_light"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<include layout="@layout/header" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/separator_up"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@color/blue_light" />

<include layout="@layout/list" />

 </LinearLayout>
```